# Is there a conceptual 2-bit-input logical operation that does: 0 0 = 0, 0 1 = 1, 1 0 = 0, 1 1 = 0?

Tags: bitwise-operators

Reason: In an LR35902 (the processor in the Game Boy) assembly program of mine, I'm trying to figure out what bits have changed to 1's when comparing A with B, which would need a bitwise operation that I'm about to ask for.

**Question: is there a name for the following bitwise operation?**

```
*-*-*-*
|A|B|O|
*-*-*-*
|0|0|0|
*-*-*-*
|0|1|1|
*-*-*-*
|1|0|0|
*-*-*-*
|1|1|0|
*-*-*-*

A = first input, B = second input and O = output.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Converse nonimplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_nonimplication). It's not very common though.

P.S. you can quickly find common names of binary logic operators [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations)

Answer (score 3):

There is no well-known binary operation with that specific map.

What you have described is (NOT A) AND B.

Comment: And the opposite (0 0 = 1, 0 1 = 0, 1 0 = 1, 1 1 = 0), as I discovered by inverting your logic, is A AND (NOT B), AKA a & !b. Isn't binary logic beautiful? ;-)

Comment: @wolfboyft Except of course, it's `A OR (NOT B)`, since `AND` changes to `OR` under negation. (This is also known as converse implication)

Comment: I would be tempted to call it "0100". :)